# Proof that the the best case complexity of quicksort is O(n log n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, quicksort

I've been looking for a proof of why an even split is the best case for the quicksort algorithm. Every anaylsis of the algorithm I've seen simply states that "the best case occurs when the partitions are as evenly balanced as possible" but stops short of proving why an even split is better than any other.

Obviously this is true, but I want to know *why.* How did we arrive at the knowledge that even splits are fast and uneven splits are slow?

Comment: Those are two different questions. O(n·log(n)) can't be used for "which is faster and which is slower", it only tells us about the runtime complexity [in the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), as `n` goes to infinity. It doesn't let us compare runtime complexity for _finite_ values of `n`. Big O tells us what _general_ behaviour to expect as we increase `n` rather than _specific_ behaviour given values of `n`, it's purely a measure of _complexity_ rather than runtime itself. So, your "real" question has [nothing to do with big O notation](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It is common enough to use "fast" and "slow" informally when comparing asymptotic complexities; if this were an exam answer or a research paper, where formality is expected, then that would be a reasonable criticism, but for a SO question this wording gets the idea across just fine. The question is why an even split is a better case than a split in any other proportion, and that can be answered perfectly well in the realm of time complexity; for this particular algorithm, big O notation is not fine-grained enough to compare, but that is not a flaw in the question.

Comment: That argument is undone by your title, because both the best case and worst still-working-case have the same runtime complexity. So you'll want to update that title to properly reflect the question. And no, for a SO question technical precision is _still_ important, SO is a technical Q&A site, the wording absolutely matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the partition sizes are in some proportion 0 ≤ *p* ≤ 1, so that an array of length n is split into two parts which are, roughly, length *pn* and (1 − *p*)*n* respectively. Then we can write the recurrence relation for the running time:

> T(*n*) = T(*pn*) + T((1 − *p*)*n*) + O(*n*)

This equation has a solution of the form T(*n*) = O(*n* log *n*) whenever 0 < *p* < 1, whereas when *p* is 0 or 1 the time complexity is quadratic instead. So let's consider just one layer of recursion, knowing that the formula is like T(*n*) ~ *n* log *n*. This also means we don't necessarily assume that other recursive calls must partition in the same proportion *p*. We can ignore the constant factor and the lower-order terms for this analysis, giving:

> T(*n*) = *pn* log *pn* + (1 − *p*)*n* log (1 − *p*)*n* + O(*n*)

The part of this which depends on *p* is just the middle two terms, which expand to:

> *pn* (log *p* + log *n*) + (1 − *p*)*n* (log (1 − *p*) + log *n*)

Some of this cancels out:

> *pn* log *p* + (1 − *p*)*n* log (1 − *p*) + *n* log *n*

We want to find *p* minimising this, so we can ignore the factor of *n* and the final *n* log *n* term which does not depend on *p*, so we are minimising

> *p* log *p* + (1 − *p*) log (1 − *p*)

It can then be seen (e.g. on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimise%20p%20log%20p%20%2B%20%281-p%29log%281-p%29%20for%200%20%3C%20p%20%3C%201)) that this is minimised when *p* = 0.5.

Comment: @Ryan The Master theorem won't work, but you can get this by considering the maximum number of "layers" of recursion as `max(log_{1/p} n, log_{1/(1-p)} n)` and observing that the O(n) term of non-recursive work adds up to a full n for each layer of recursion. This gives either `n log_{1/p} n` or `n log_{1/(1-p)} n` as an upper bound depending on the value of p, which is assumed (for this analysis) to be a constant. This argument is made in trincot's answer.

Comment: Sorry, right as I hit send on the question the answer popped into my mind. Thanks for your very quick response.

For those seeking context the original question was along the lines of
"Why can T(n) = T(pn) + T((1 − p)n) + O(n) be reduced to T(n) = O(n log n)?"

Answer (score 2):

> How did we arrive at the knowledge that even splits are fast and uneven splits are slow?

It is not true that only even splits lead to the best case complexity of O(log).

Even if you split consistently with a distribution factor 1/10 versus 9/10, the overall time complexity will still be O(log).

The best time complexity is lost whenever the size of the partitions are no longer guaranteed to be at least a minimal *fraction* of the current array size. So when a partition can get size 10 (a constant) *irrespective* of the current array size, then the optimum is lost.

As you might know, the optimum is not reached when an already sorted array (without duplicates) is sorted with quick sort that chooses the first or last element as pivot. This is because then one partition will always have size 1 (a constant, irrespective of the current array size).

#### Proof

The statement to prove is this:

Given a constant , with 1 <  ≤ 2. If it can be guaranteed that a (sub)array of size  will never be split into a partition that has a size greater than / (rounded upwards), then the time complexity of quick sort is O(log). An example of  is 1.1

It is clear that most time will be spent on the largest partition. So if we "follow" those partitions as they are created recursively, we get partition sizes of , /, /², /³, ..., 1. Let +1 be the length of this sequence. It corresponds to the maximum depth of the recursion tree. The series stops at term  (a term which is 1) when:

/ ≤ 1

≤

log ≤

In terms of asymptotic time complexity, the base of the logarithm is irrelevant (as long as it is a constant greater than 1, which is true in our case), and so we can conclude that  -- the maximum depth of recursion -- is O(log).

We can see that each individual value in the original array will be part of exactly one partition on each level of recursion. In the worst case the number of levels it is participating in is , but it could participate in fewer levels when it gets into the *smaller* partition in a split leading sooner to a partition size of 1 at a recursion level less than . We take however the worst case of  recursion levels.

At each level a particular value takes part in O(1) operations (compare and move). Here we can ignore that the pivot takes part in many comparisons, as we assign that work to the other value that takes part in that comparison.

Therefore we have a total time complexity of O(log).

### Practical execution time

While big O time complexity is the guiding principle for evaluating an algorithm's running time, we can expect a difference in actual, measured running times when running quick sort on the same inputs sizes, but with different values of .

As derived above, the depth of the recursion tree  is at most ceil(log). This value is minimised when  is maximised, and  can be at the most 2. By consequence =2 will on average give the best execution times in comparison with other values of . When  is 2 we have the "perfect" scenario where each partition divides the array in half.

Comment: This argument works if you are only trying to show O(n log n) for any partition proportions, but it doesn't show that equal-sized partitions are optimal. For the latter it's not sufficient to treat every element as if it occurs in every level of recursion, because then you are only comparing upper bounds with other upper bounds.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Big O is an upper bound, right? The proof provided is for a const , and when that  is 2, we have the *even* partitioning case, right?

Comment: I'm saying that if you try to extend this argument to compare the performance for different values of r, then what you'll get is something like `n log_r n` as an upper bound for each r, but then that doesn't imply that r=2 is a better proportion than, say, r=1.5, you will only have shown that the upper bound `n log_2 n` is smaller than the upper bound `n log_1.5 n`.

Comment: Yes, I did not intend to prove that =2 is *better*. I intended to prove that for any constant  in the given range, the time complexity is the *optimal* time complexity, which is O(log).  Like I wrote in my answer, the base of the logarithm is irrelevant when speaking in terms of big O.

Comment: Right. But the question asks *"why an even split is better than any other"*. This answer shows that it's as good as any other in terms of big O; if we look finer-grained than big O then it is possible to show that even splits are better than non-even splits. I'm not saying your answer is bad, just that there is more to say about the issue.

Comment: You can't use big O notation to determine "which is better". Big O only gives you the complexity in terms of factors of `n`, with any constants removed, because they don't affect the run in the limit. n·log(n) and 10000000000·n·log(n) have the same big O complexity.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, If you are answering to me: yes, I know what asymptotic complexity means. I can just repeat my previous comment: I did not intend to prove that =2 is better.  I intended to prove that for any constant  in the given range, the time complexity is the optimal time complexity.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't know how you read my comments and reached the conclusion that I "seem to think" that - I explicitly said that you need something more fine-grained than big O notation to determine that an even split is the best proportion. So as far as I can tell, you are repeating what I said back to me.